# 1990 US Census Block Boundary File?

Tags: data, census, united-states

Does anyone here know of a source from which 1990 Census Block polygons can be downloaded? For Illinois, specifically, if not for the entire country? The Census Bureau has ["no plans to create Block level boundary files"](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/bdy_files.html), and I know that NHGIS doesn't have the block-level data. I searched the old questions here and found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get Illinois TIGER 1999 in TIGER/Line format (by county) from:

ftp://ftp.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER1999/IL/

Use [GDAL/OGR](http://www.gdal.org/) to extract all polygons. Those *should* be the blocks. GDAL/OGR comes with a Python script called tigerpoly.py that will do this for you.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I love GIS.SE; I didn't think I had a chance of finding this data.